Rigorous $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof of L'Hôpital's rule
In this post, I would like to ask a question about the rigorous $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof of L'Hôpital's rule. One case was bothering me a bit, and after some thought, I believe I have figured it out. However, I would like to confirm that I am understanding everything correctly.
Let $\widehat{\mathbb{R}}:=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm \infty\}\cup \{\infty\}$.

Theorem (L'Hôpital's rule). Let $-\infty \leq a < b \leq +\infty$, and let $f, g : (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable functions on
$(a, b)$ with $g'(x) \neq 0$ on $(a, b)$. Assume $\lim\limits_{x \to
 b-} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = A$, where $A \in \widehat{\mathbb{R}}$.
Then in either of the following two cases:

$\lim\limits_{x \to b-} g(x) = \infty$,
$\lim\limits_{x \to b-} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to b-} g(x) = 0$,

we have $\lim\limits_{x \to b-} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = A$.

First of all, we notice that by Rolle's theorem, $g$ is strictly monotonic on $(a,b)$, and we can make the interval $(a,b)$ smaller so that $g$ does not vanish on it. WLOG, we assume that $g(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in (a,b)$.

Consider the case when $\lim\limits_{x \to b-} g(x) = \infty$ with $A\in \mathbb{R}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then $\exists \delta_1=\delta_1(\epsilon)>0$ s.t. $\forall t\in (b-\delta_1,b)$ we have: $\left|\frac{f'(t)}{g'(t)}-A\right|<\epsilon$.
Then $\exists \delta_2=\delta_2(\epsilon)>0$ s.t. $\forall t\in (b-\delta_2,b)$ we have: $\left|\frac{f'(t)}{g'(t)}\right|<M$, where $M>0$.
Let $\delta_3=\min \{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ and fix $y\in (b-\delta_3,b)$, let's say $y=b-\frac{\delta_3}{2}$. Then $\exists \delta_4=\delta_4(\epsilon)>0$ s.t. $\forall t\in (b-\delta_4,b)$ we have: $|g(t)|\geq \frac{\max\{|f(y)|,|g(y)|\}+1}{\epsilon}$.
Let $\delta=\min\{b-y,\delta_4\}>0$. Then for any $x\in (b-\delta,b)$, which implies $y<x$ by Cauchy's theorem we have: $\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{g(y)-g(y)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$ for some $c\in (y,x)$. After some algebraic manipulations and triangle inequality, we obtain:
$$\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-A\right|\leq \left|\frac{f(y)}{g(x)}\right|+\left|\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}-A\right|+\left|\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}\right|\leq \epsilon+\epsilon+M \epsilon=\epsilon(M+2).$$
Therefore, we have shown that $\lim\limits_{x \to b-} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = A$.

Now, we consider the case $\lim\limits_{x \to b-} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to b-} g(x) = 0$, which is a bit different, although the approach is still based on Cauchy's theorem. Let's assume that $A\in \mathbb{R}$, $b\in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then $\exists \delta=\delta(\epsilon)>0$ s.t. $\forall t\in (b-\delta,b)$, we have: $\left|\frac{f'(t)}{g'(t)}-A\right|<\epsilon$ and $\left|\frac{f'(t)}{g'(t)}\right|<M$, where $M>0$. Take any $x\in (b-\delta,b)$. We note that $\exists \delta_3>0$ s.t. $\forall t\in (b-\delta_3,b)$ we have: $|f(t)|\leq \epsilon |g(x)|$, $|g(t)|\leq \epsilon |g(x)|$. Now let's pick $y>x$ such that $y\in (b-\delta_3,b)$ and by Cauchy's theorem we have: $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{g(x)-g(y)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$ for some $c\in (x,y)$. After some algebraic manipulations and triangle inequality:
$$\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-A\right|\leq \left|\frac{f(y)}{g(x)}\right|+\left|\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}-A\right|+\left|\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}\right|\leq \epsilon (2+M).$$
Is the second part of the proof correct? At least I don’t see any mistakes, it looks good to me. Thanks!

Why did you number the cases, swap them round, then renumber them?

@J.G., Thanks for the remark. Fixed!

I am confused by your definition of $\widehat{\Bbb R}$. It includes three infinities ${-\infty, +\infty, \infty}$? How is convergence to $\infty$ defined, as opposed to the other two?

@PaulSinclair, Let's write all three definitions, depending on whether the limit is $-\infty, +\infty$, or $\infty$. Suppose $\lim\limits_{x \to b-} h(x) = A$, where for concreteness $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A \in {-\infty, +\infty, \infty}$.


$\lim\limits_{x\to b-} h(x)=-\infty$ means $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta=\delta(\epsilon)>0$ s.t. $\forall t\in (b-\delta,b)$, we have $f(t)<-\epsilon$.


$\lim\limits_{x\to b-} h(x)=+\infty$ means $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta=\delta(\epsilon)>0$ s.t. $\forall t\in (b-\delta,b)$, we have $f(t)>\epsilon$.



@PaulSinclair, 3. $\lim\limits_{x\to b-} h(x)=\infty$ means $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists \delta=\delta(\epsilon)>0$ s.t. $\forall t\in (b-\delta,b)$, we have $|f(t)|>\epsilon$.
